# Broadcaster/Listener pattern using variadic templates

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to implement a sort of a Broadcaster/Listener pattern using variadic template:

```
template <typename... Args>
class WithListeners {
public:
    class Listener {
    public:
        virtual void operator()(Args&&... args) = 0;
    };
private:
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<Listener>> listeners;
public:
    void addListener(std::shared_ptr<Listener> l) {
        if (std::find(listeners.begin(), listeners.end(), l) == listeners.end())
            listeners.push_back(l);
    }
    void removeListener(std::shared_ptr<Listener> l) {
        listeners.remove(l);
    }
    void callListeners(Args&&... args) const {
        for (auto l : listeners) {
            if (l) (*l)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    }
};
```

The thing is that I can compile it with `<>` but not with `<int>`. So for example this doesn't compile:

```
class MyClassWithListener : public WithListeners<int>::Listener{
public:
    virtual void operator()(int value) override {
        //my handling code
    }
};
```

It says that the function with override specifier does not override any base class method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may think that your `operator()` makes use of perfect forwarding, but it does not. The `Args...` template argument is fully resolved by the time the `operator()` method is being considered, so it just takes all arguments as regular RValue references.

Because of that, your override needs to do the same thing:

```
class MyClassWithListener : public WithListeners<int>::Listener{
public:
    virtual void operator()(int&& value) override {
        //my handling code
    }
};
```

You would be better served to just go with straight arguments in this case:

```
template <typename... Args>
class WithListeners {
public:
    class Listener {
    public:
      virtual void operator()(Args... args) = 0;
    };

    void callListeners(Args... args) const {
        for (auto l : listeners) {
            if (l) (*l)(std::move(args)...);
        }
    }
};
```

Since you can still fully define the arguments of the listener:

```
class MyClassWithListener : public WithListeners<const int&>::Listener{
public:
    virtual void operator()(const int& value) override {
        //my handling code
    }
};
```